# Is there any test GIT repository available?

Tags: git

I want to learn git, so is there any online test git repository available, Just for test? so that I can learn how to work with remote GIT repos?

Comment: Google for `Github Hello World`. You will get many like this: https://github.com/kelseyhightower/helloworld

Comment: This GitHub repository looks interesting to test and is especially made by a popular website for learning: https://github.com/w3schools-test/w3schools-test.github.io

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can clone any repo you like at github.com. 
If you need more functionality (merging, pushing, etc.), you can create your own testing repo there (currently this is free) - http://help.github.com/creating-a-repo/

Comment: But I also want to do commit and Branch Merge!

Comment: well, you can create a test repo there. There are unlimited public repositories in the free plan they have in the current moment (https://github.com/plans) [edit - I'm not affiliated with github in any way; I'm just a user there]

Comment: Committing, merging, etc... are all done locally.  The only thing you wouldn't be able to do is push to the foreign repo.  Otherwise, as siride says, you can do all of this (including have a remote repo) on your one computer quite easily.

Answer (score 16):

Git isn't like SVN in that you don't need a central repo.  What you can do is take a directory full of files and make a copy.  In the copy, run "git init" and voila, you have a git repo to play with.  You can even clone from it locally and practice pushing and pulling.  You can do this all without even being connected to the internet.

Answer (score 8):

Well, this is older question but it can be still very current for others.

I usually use the following work flow (it is more or less what siride answer is suggesting). It is usable for testing Git or for having the remote repository at network drive or service such as Dropbox (instead of github.com or others).

Create a directory which will act as a remote repository:

```
cd /somewhere/on/hard/drive/eg/Dropbox
mkdir my_project
cd my_project
git init --bare
```

Go to the existing project directory (or create if you don't have any):

```
cd project_dir
git init
# add all files you want to add, e.g. *, *.cpp *.h, '*.cpp' etc. or one by one
# create some file if you don't have any
git add *
git commit -am "initial commit"
```

Still in the project directory, connect to the remote repository:

```
# add the remote repository
git remote add origin /somewhere/on/hard/drive/eg/Dropbox
# push for the first time
git push -u origin master
```

Then you can `git commit`, `git push`, `git pull` or whatever you want try. To create a new clone of that repository use standard clone:

```
git clone /somewhere/on/hard/drive/eg/Dropbox my_project_dir
```

This works great for testing because it does not require any sever or third party service and it is usable even for the real work.

Alternatively, for complete beginners, http://try.github.io/ which allows you to try basic Git commands in your web browser.

Answer (score 5):

And here is the repo where you can test do the `pull request` https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife